# $push not creating new array field. Using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, push

Working on a blog site. In MongoDB my blog posts don't have a comments field to start out. I would like to use $push to add a comments field and add the comment value. The code below doesnt throw any errors, the console.log fires but when I check the fields in MongoDB nothing has changed.

```
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
    postid,
    {$push:{"comments": comment}},
    {new: true},
    function(err, added){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log('\n-------- Comment Added ----------\n');
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    }
);
```

EDIT: I figured out that this is because I didn't have a comment field set up in the schema. But now that I added it, how do I deal with the comment field being undefined initially? I have jade code that lists all of the comments if they exist:

```
if post.comments
        h3 Comments
        each comment, i in comments
            .comment
                p.comment-name #{comment.name}
                p.comment-text #{comment.body}
```

But I get error:

```
p.comment-text #{comment.body} Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mariya! The problem is that you cant push new fields into mongoose models. All fields have to be defined before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try with $addToSet instead of $push.

```
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
postid,
{$addToSet:{"comments": comment}},
{new: true},
function(err, added){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log('\n-------- Comment Added ----------\n');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: but theres no array there in the first place

Comment: doesnt addtoset just add to an existing array instead of creating a new field?

Comment: Thats what i JUST figured out! There was no comment field in the schema :) I just added it but now I have another problem on the Jade page. The Jade page is supposed to show comments for a post IF there are comments. But when there are no comments, it has trouble dealing with it because it is undefined. Can I set it to something other than undefined in the schema?

Comment: You defined comment field as array right? So you can check by its length whether it has elements or not

Comment: OK got it working by checking length now. The Jade error was a separate issue. The loop should be each comment, i in *post*.comments